# Owner not able to write log file

Tags: ubuntu, cron, chmod, python3

I'm working on a python script, I created a file in /var/log/ folder with 664 permissions

python script is not able to write logs to the file created, IDK why... since file owner is ubuntu(aws's default user).

very carefully I have given Read and Write permission to the file

scheduled crontab failed to run the app because of permission denied issue. Any ideas?

i) the command you used to set up the crontab - `crontab -e`
ii) the crontab line that is running the python script - `*/30 * * * * python3 /home/ubuntu/message_initiator.py`
iii) the exact error message - `Permission denied: '/var/log/ice-message-initiator.log'`

Comment: can the owner travel the directories below?

Comment: yes, I can go inside any folder and see the content.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and include: i) the command you used to set up the crontab, ii) the crontab line that is running the python script and iii) the exact error message.

Comment: added more details for clarity in question.

Comment: @epsan Who is the cronjob running as? The `ubuntu` user?

Comment: @NasirRiley Yeah, Thats one part of my question, ideally it should be ubuntu since, the user who created is ubuntu. and its part of administrator group yet it failed to read log file which clearly has group write permission. I haven't. used `sudo` to run it in cron.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you run

```
ll -d /var/log
```

Then you'll see that it is owned by `root` (possibly with `syslog` as the group) and has 755 or 775 permissions which means that while others can read and traverse the directory, only `root` (and possibly `syslog`) can modify it. `ice-message-initiator.log` is in `/var/log` and while `ubuntu` is its owner, `ubuntu` doesn't have modify permissions to `/var/log` which means that it can't modify its contents whether they are files or directories. The error isn't occurring because the `ubuntu` user can't read the file but because it can't write to the file due to not having modify permissions to its parent directory, `/var/log`.

To have your cronjob work, you either need to either run it as `root` or have it write the log file into a subdirectory such as `/var/log/ice` and give `ubuntu` modify permissions to it.